# Reading a file line by line and splitting the string into tokens in c

Tags: c, file

I am reading a file line by line and splitting the string into tokens.

```
int main()
{
    FILE* fp;
    char  line[255];

    fp = fopen("file.txt" , "r");
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL)
    {   
        char val1[16];
        char val2[9];

        strcpy(val1, strtok(line, ","));
        strcpy(val2, strtok(NULL, ","));

        printf("%s|%s\n", val1, val2);          
    }
}
```

My input file content (file.txt)

```
182930101222, KLA1512
182930101223, KLA1513
182930101224, KLA1514
182930101225, KLA1515
```

When I print get

```
 | KLA1512
```

Instead of

```
182930101222| KLA1512
```

What is the issue ?

Comment: debug your code print `line` before strcpy calls to know why `val1` is `\0`.

Comment: It seems the time has come to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18420057/905902 (same but without the loop)

Comment: @wildplasser: Not really, the former question had `val2[7]` instead of `val2[9]`.

Comment: Perhaps you should be better go and use `awk` to solve your issue?

Comment: But then he did  not have "\n" at the end of the string. (or maybe even "\r\n" )

Comment: In previous post you got it working by changing 7 to 9, now change 9 to 10 :D

Comment: Or _just to be on the safe side_ change them both to 255.

Comment: Actually, your code is working for me.

Comment: But, my txt file doesn't have `\r` characters...

Answer (score 6):

Your problem (again) is that you're not allocating enough space for an array, and overwriting the end of it.  The irony is that in this case, you don't even need to allocate any (additional) arrays.  `strtok()` is tokenizing the `line[]` array, overwriting the delimiters with `'\0'` chars, and those are sufficient for your needs.

```
int main()
{
    FILE* fp;
    char  line[255];

    fp = fopen("file.txt" , "r");
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL)
    {
        const char* val1 = strtok(line, ",");
        const char* val2 = strtok(NULL, ",");

        printf("%s|%s\n", val1, val2);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you how to remove newline and whitespace from char array  in c.

Comment: @user2684719 - Removing _leading_ and _trailing_ whitespace from a modifiable `char` buffer is not difficult at all.  I could write the function & post it for you, but how would that help you learn?  Your `line[255]` buffer is modifiable by you in whatever way you see fit.  You're already modifying it by calling `strtok()` on it (overwriting the `','` delimiters with nul characters (`'\0'`) which turns the buffer into separate C-style strings (which you keep track of with pointers `val1` and `val2`).  Now, just write a new function of your own to remove leading & trailing whitespace....

Comment: A suitable function signature would be: `char* remove_whitespace(char* str)`.  With that function signature, you take a C-style string pointer, the function modifies the string as necessary, and returns a pointer to the same string with whitespace removed.  If there is no leading whitespace, it'll just return the same pointer address that was passed to it.  In the function, you loop from the start until the first non-whitespace character (see `isspace()`).  When you find it, that's the new start of the string (which you need to keep track of in a pointer, because that's the pointer to return.)

Comment: Then keep looping until you find the end of the string (i.e. until you encounter the terminating `'\0'` character).  Then scan _backwards_ until you find the first non-whitespace character, _or_ you find the start pointer address (either way).  When you find it, simply write `'\0'` to the address one greater than that, which terminates the string at that point (truncating any whitespace, which includes any newline chars).

Comment: @user2684719 - BTW, if you found an answer on this page to be useful, please select it as "the best" answer.  That's how you "pay" people for helping you.  Also optionally up-vote any answers that were helpful even if you didn't select them as "the best" answer.

Answer (score 0):

`fgets` inserts a newline

simply increase `val2` size by 1 i.e. `val2[10]`

or remove trailing `'\n'`

```
while( fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL ){ 
        char val1[16] ,val2[9];
        char *pos;
        if ((pos=strchr(line, '\n')) != NULL)
            *pos = '\0';
        strcpy(val1 , strtok(line,","));
        strcpy(val2 , strtok(NULL,","));
        printf("%s|%s\n",val1, val2);           
}
```